# Como passar parâmetros para a view _Layout.cshtml em projetos Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Olá, vendo que tenho uma `Area` de painel de controle o meu layout basicamente muda só o centro com as `views`, porém quero por funcionalidades na parte em que fica o `_Layout.cshtml`, e para tais funções preciso acessar o objeto da pessoa logada. Como irei fazer isto?

Comment: Eu uso uma classe UsuarioRepositorio onde tenho um método static chamado GetUsuarioLogado() que verifica se o usuário está logado e me retorna os dados deste usuário.

Como você está fazendo a sua autenticação?

Comment: coloque como resposa e também código para eu poder entender melhor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nos meus projetos costumo utilizar uma Classe `static` chamada `UsuarioRepositorio` Como segue abaixo:

```
public class UsuarioRepositorio
    {
        public static bool AutenticarUsuario(string login, string senha)
        {
            var context = new NewsContext();

            var user = context.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Login == login && u.Status);

            if (user == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (!Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(user.Senha, senha))
            {
                return false;
            }

            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Login, false);

            return true;
        }

        public static User GetLogedUser()
        {
            if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return null;

            var login = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

            var context = new NewsContext();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(login))
            {
                return null;
            }

            var user = context.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Login == login && u.Status);
            return user;
        }

        public static void LogOf()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        }
    }
```

Onde tenho 3 métodos, `AutenticarUsuario`, `GetLogedUser` e `LogOf`.

Quando preciso fazer alguma ação que necessito pegar as informações do usuário logado como por exemplo: Imprimir o nome do Usuário logado no Painel Administrativo.

Eu uso assim:

```
@using Projeto.Repositorio

<label>Bem vindo: @UsuarioRepositorio.GetLogedUser().Nome</label>
```

Funciona perfeitamente para mim.

E você pode usar de outras maneiras, como por exemplo verificar se o usuário tem alguma propriedade ou `Role` que o define como Admin e imprimir somente os itens do menu permitido para a regra onde ele se encontra.

Segue [link](http://devbrasil.net/profiles/blogs/autentica-o-e-permiss-es-de-usu-rios-em-asp-net-mvc-4) do Artigo onde aprendi a usar esses métodos.